# Searching for specific sub-arrays in a multidimensional array, then loop through the found sub-arrays to get all the values

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array, arrays

I need to search the following array for the sub-arrays that start with "prod_", then loop through those sub-arrays to get all the values. The amount of sub-arrays can vary depending on how many products in the cart.

```
    Array
    (
        [address] => clayton85
        [prod_0] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 2
                [style] => American Apparel T-Shirt
                [color] => Royal
                [size] => Medium
                [price] => 33.90
            )

        [prod_1] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 1
                [style] => Bella Womens T-Shirt
                [color] => Teal
                [size] => Large
                [price] => 17.95
            )

        [prod_2] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 1
                [style] => Canvas Long Sleeve
                [color] => Red
                [size] => Large
                [price] => 19.95
            )

        [prod_3] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 1
                [style] => Canvas Long Sleeve
                [color] => Red
                [size] => Medium
                [price] => 19.95
            )

        [cartTotal] => 91.75
    )
```

I was able to come up with a very messy solution that returns the values by count, but there must be a better, more efficient way. Using PHP 5.5 this is what I came up with.

```
    <?php
$cartArray  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$item_cnt = 0;
foreach ($cartArray as $prod => $option) {
    if (strpos($prod, "prod_") === 0) {
        echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="co-product">';
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($cartArray[$prod] as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0) {echo '<span class="label">' . $value . '</span>'; $item_cnt = $item_cnt + intval($value);}
            elseif ($i === 1) {echo '<span class="co-desc">' . $value . '<br>';}
            elseif ($i === 2) {echo '<span class="co-subtext"><strong>Color:</strong> ' . $value . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>';}
            elseif ($i === 3) {echo '<span class="co-subtext"><strong>Size:</strong> ' . $value . '</span></span>';}
            else {echo '<span class="co-price pull-right">$' . $value . '</span>';}
            $i++;
        }
        echo '</div></div></div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the main array and then just use the keys of the inner array:

```
foreach ($cartArray as $prod => $option) {
    if (strpos($prod, "prod_") === 0) {
        echo $option["qty"];
        //etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I knew I was making it way more complex than it needed to be.